# How to upload large files (around 10GB)

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I want to transfer to my Amazon S3 bucket an archive of around 10GB, using a PHP script (it's a backup script).

I actually use the following code :

```
$uploader = new \Aws\S3\MultipartCopy($s3Client, $tmpFilesBackupDirectory, [
        'Bucket' => 'MyBucketName',
        'Key'    => 'backup'.date('Y-m-d').'.tar.gz',
        'StorageClass' => $storageClass,
        'Tagging' => 'expiration='.$tagging,
        'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
    ]);

try
{
    $result = $uploader->copy();
    echo "Upload complete: {$result['ObjectURL']}\n";
}
catch (Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

My issue is that after few minutes (let's say 10mn), I receive an error message from the apache server : 504 Gateway timeout.
I understand that this error is related to the configuration of my Apache server, but I don't want to increase the timeout of my server.

My idea is to use the PHP SDK Low-Level API to do the following steps:

1. Use Aws\S3\S3Client::uploadPart() method in order to manually upload 5 parts, and store the response obtained in $_SESSION (I need the ETag values to complete the upload);
2. Reload the page using header('Location: xxx');
3. Perform again the first 2 steps for the next 5 parts, until all parts are uploaded;
4. Finalise the upload using Aws\S3\S3Client::completeMultipartUpload().

I suppose that this should work but before to use this method, I'd like to know if there is an easier way to achieve my goal, for example by using the high-level API...

Any suggestions?

NOTE : I'm not searching for some existing script : my main goal is to learn how to fix this issue :)

Best regards,

Lionel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question (I hope it might help someone one day!), he is how I fixed my issue, step by step:

1/ When I load my page, I check if the archive already exists. If not, I create my .tar.gz file and I reload the page using header().
I noticed that this step was quite slow since there is lot of data to archive. That's why I reload my page to avoid any timeout during the next steps!

2/ If the backup file exists, I use AWS MultipartUpload to send 10 chunks of 100MB each. Everytime that a chunk is sent successfully, I update a session variable ($_SESSION['backup']['partNumber']) to know what is the next chunk that needs to be uploaded.
Once my 10 chunks are sent, I reload the page again to avoid any timeout.

3/ I repeat the second step until the upload of all parts is done, using my session variable to know which part of the upload needs to be sent next.

4/ Finally, I complete the multipart upload and I delete the archive stored locally.

You can of course send more than 10 times 100MB before to reload your page. I chose this value to be sure that I won't reach a timeout even if the download is slow. But I guess I could send easilly around 5GB each time without issue.
Note: You cannot redirect you script to itself too much time. There is a limit (I think it's around 20 times for Chrome and Firefoxbefore to get an error, and more for IE). In my case (the archive is around 10GB), transfering 1GB per reload is fine (the page will be reloaded around 10 times). But it the archive size increases, I'll have to send more chunks each time.

Here is my full script. I could surely be improved, but it's working quite well for now and it may help someone having similar issue!

```
public function backup()
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '1800');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

    require ROOT.'/Public/scripts/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

    $s3Client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'eu-west-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '',
            'secret' => '',
        ],
    ]);

    $tmpDBBackupDirectory = ROOT.'Var/Backups/backup'.date('Y-m-d').'.sql.gz';
    if(!file_exists($tmpDBBackupDirectory))
    {
        $this->cleanInterruptedMultipartUploads($s3Client);
        $this->createSQLBackupFile();
        $this->uploadSQLBackup($s3Client, $tmpDBBackupDirectory);
    }

    $tmpFilesBackupDirectory = ROOT.'Var/Backups/backup'.date('Y-m-d').'.tar.gz';
    if(!isset($_SESSION['backup']['archiveReady']))
    {
        $this->createFTPBackupFile();
        header('Location: '.CURRENT_URL);
    }

    $this->uploadFTPBackup($s3Client, $tmpFilesBackupDirectory);

    unlink($tmpDBBackupDirectory);
    unlink($tmpFilesBackupDirectory);
}

public function createSQLBackupFile()
{
    // Backup DB
    $tmpDBBackupDirectory = ROOT.'Var/Backups/backup'.date('Y-m-d').'.sql.gz';

    if(!file_exists($tmpDBBackupDirectory))
    {
        $return_var = NULL;
        $output = NULL;
        $dbLogin = '';
        $dbPassword = '';
        $dbName = '';
        $command = 'mysqldump -u '.$dbLogin.' -p'.$dbPassword.' '.$dbName.' --single-transaction --quick | gzip > '.$tmpDBBackupDirectory;
        exec($command, $output, $return_var);
    }

    return $tmpDBBackupDirectory;
}


public function createFTPBackupFile()
{
    // Compacting all files
    $tmpFilesBackupDirectory = ROOT.'Var/Backups/backup'.date('Y-m-d').'.tar.gz';

    $command = 'tar -cf '.$tmpFilesBackupDirectory.' '.ROOT;
    exec($command);

    $_SESSION['backup']['archiveReady'] = true;

    return $tmpFilesBackupDirectory;
}


public function uploadSQLBackup($s3Client, $tmpDBBackupDirectory)
{
    $result = $s3Client->putObject([
        'Bucket' => '',
        'Key'    => 'backup'.date('Y-m-d').'.sql.gz',
        'SourceFile' => $tmpDBBackupDirectory,
        'StorageClass' => '',
        'Tagging' => '',
        'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
    ]);
}


public function uploadFTPBackup($s3Client, $tmpFilesBackupDirectory)
{
    $storageClass = 'STANDARD_IA';
    $bucket = '';
    $key = 'backup'.date('Y-m-d').'.tar.gz';
    $chunkSize = 100 * 1024 * 1024; // 100MB
    $reloadFrequency = 10;

    if(!isset($_SESSION['backup']['uploadId']))
    {
        $response = $s3Client->createMultipartUpload([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key'    => $key,
            'StorageClass' => $storageClass,
            'Tagging' => '',
            'ServerSideEncryption' => 'AES256',
        ]);
        $_SESSION['backup']['uploadId'] = $response['UploadId'];
        $_SESSION['backup']['partNumber'] = 1;
    }

    $file = fopen($tmpFilesBackupDirectory, 'r');
    $parts = array();

    //Reading parts already uploaded
    for($i = 1; $i < $_SESSION['backup']['partNumber']; $i++)
    {
        if(!feof($file))
        {
            fread($file, $chunkSize);
        }
    }

    // Uploading next parts
    while(!feof($file))
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                $result = $s3Client->uploadPart(array(
                    'Bucket'     => $bucket,
                    'Key'        => $key,
                    'UploadId'   => $_SESSION['backup']['uploadId'],
                    'PartNumber' => $_SESSION['backup']['partNumber'],
                    'Body'       => fread($file, $chunkSize),
                ));
            }
        }
        while (!isset($result));

        $_SESSION['backup']['parts'][] = array(
            'PartNumber' => $_SESSION['backup']['partNumber'],
            'ETag'       => $result['ETag'],
        );
        $_SESSION['backup']['partNumber']++;

        if($_SESSION['backup']['partNumber'] % $reloadFrequency == 1)
        {
            header('Location: '.CURRENT_URL);
            die;
        }
    }
    fclose($file);

    $result = $s3Client->completeMultipartUpload(array(
        'Bucket'   => $bucket,
        'Key'      => $key,
        'UploadId' => $_SESSION['backup']['uploadId'],
        'MultipartUpload' => Array(
            'Parts'    => $_SESSION['backup']['parts'],
        ),
    ));
    $url = $result['Location'];
}


public function cleanInterruptedMultipartUploads($s3Client)
{
    $tResults = $s3Client->listMultipartUploads(array('Bucket' => ''));
    $tResults = $tResults->toArray();

    if(isset($tResults['Uploads']))
    {
        foreach($tResults['Uploads'] AS $result)
        {
            $s3Client->abortMultipartUpload(array(
                'Bucket'   => '', 
                'Key'      => $result['Key'], 
                'UploadId' => $result['UploadId']));
        }
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['backup']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['backup']);
    }
}
```

If someone has questions don't hesitate to contact me :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the AWS CLI to copy the file?  You can create a script in the CLI and that way everything is AWS native. (Amazon has a [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/backup-to-s3-cli/) on that.) You can use the scp command:

```
scp -i Amazonkey.pem /local/path/backupfile.tar.gz ec2-user@Elastic-IP-of-ec2-2:/path/backupfile.tar.gz
```

From my perspective, it would be easier to do the work within AWS, which has features to move files and data. If you'd like to use a shell script, this [article](https://n2ws.com/blog/how-to-guides/automate-amazon-ec2-instance-backup) on automating EC2 backups has a good one, plus more detail on backup options.

Comment: Hello Ben,Thanks for your answer. I guess that you need to install something on the server in order to use AWS CLI. And I don't have root access to the server. But except that yes, it could be a valid option in another scenario :)